# in python assign a value based on dictionary mapping

Tags: python

I was wondering if someone could explain this to me:

```
In [400]: poz0=''

In [401]: poz1=''

In [402]: poz={0:poz0, 1:poz1}

In [403]: for i in range(1):
   .....:     poz[i]='some value '+str(i)
   .....:

In [404]:

In [405]: poz[0]
Out[405]: 'some value 0'

In [406]: poz0
Out[406]: ''
```

I was expecting for poz0 to be == poz[0], same for poz1, but its not. Anyone could explain why?

Thanks

Comment: try this for a change ... a = 1; b = a; a = 4; print b ... will result 1 ... So when you assign poz[0] = poz0, you put inside poz[0] the value not the instance. In that "for" you change the initial value with another;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reassigned `poz[0]` to a different object, namely the value of `'some value '+str(0)`. The assignment operator `=` does not modify `poz[0]`'s value but changing the binding in the `dict`.

Comment: i believe Diego's answer is correct ... poz[0] does not contain any reference to poz0 object ... poz0 = 100; poz={0:poz0}; print poz; poz0 = 1000; print poz; ... no changes

Comment: @StefanNch: Your reasoning is flawed. `poz[0]` does contain a reference to the value of `poz0` after `poz[0] = poz0`, but in your example, you then reassign `poz0` itself.

Answer (score 2):

The values are different because `str` instances are built-in immutable objects (numbers, strings, tuples, frozensets). So when you create the dictionary in `poz={0:poz0, 1:poz1}` you are actually doing the same as `poz={0:'', 1:''}`.

`poz0` is not linked in any way with `poz[0]`, there are different objects.

Update answering the comment:

With a list is not the same behaviour because lists are mutable objects:

```
In [9]: l = [1,2,3]

In [10]: d = {0: l}
In [12]: d[0]

Out[12]: [1, 2, 3]

In [13]: d[0].append(4)

In [14]: d[0]
Out[14]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [15]: l
Out[15]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: While true, this is not the reason for the behavior. With lists, similar behavior would have been displayed: `d = {0: [1]}; d[0] = [2]`.

Comment: Ok, I finally catch you. That's because the assignment.

Comment: right, i got confused, now i clearly see that poz[0] gets overwritten in the for loop